# Recover an Xcode project from an app on your iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Well, yesterday I was dump enough to somehow erase the main disk of my MacBook. All my files are gone. I have no backup. The only thing I am concerned about is my app. I am reaaally close to perfecting it, however i don't have the Xcode project. Can I somehow retrieve it from my iPhone, in which I was testing it on?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, mate you have lost the project.

Comment: Check recovery options for hard disk. No other way to retrieve code.

Comment: @ravi.p ohhh noo. I lost months of work

Comment: @FilipposT best practice commit your code on Github, bit bucket or use any cloud storage so it safe in all circumstances